# Поиск по командам в linux

Tags: linux, документация

В играх на source есть очень удобная команда find, которая позволяет искать по всем командам и их описанию. И тут я подумал, а нет ли чего-нибудь подобного под linux?

Comment: В гугле `man` нужно добавить, чтобы по manpages поиск происходил.

Comment: man -k ... пробовали?

Comment: @avp попробовал, именно то, что нужно. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну и хорошо. Если после man -k строк много, то вместе с grep удобней получается (впрочем, наверное сами бы догадались)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## help

для внутренних команд оболочки (*cd*, *echo*, *exit* и т.д. и т.п.) есть внутренняя команда оболочки *help*:

```
$ help command
```

если после набора `help` поставить пробел и нажать два раза <kbd>tab</kbd>, то отобразится список внутренних команд оболочки, для которых можно получить справку. начать лучше с:

```
$ help help
```

---

## man

многие программы/команды/функции имеют т.н. *man-страницу* с детальным описанием аргументов/опций/клавиатурных сокращений для запуска/использования. просмотреть их можно с помощью программы *man*:

```
$ man zip
```

если после набора `man` поставить пробел и нажать два раза <kbd>tab</kbd>, то отобразится список *man-страниц*, которые можно почитать. начать лучше с:

```
$ man man
```

### apropos

программа apropos позволяет искать по заголовкам и кратким описаниям *man-страниц* ключевые слова. например:

```
$ apropos reboot
```

---

## info

программы, разрабатываемые в рамках проекта [gnu](http://gnu.org), обычно имеют документацию в формате [*texinfo*](https://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/), к которой можно обратиться с помощью программы *info*:

```
$ info gcc
```

если после набора `info` поставить пробел и нажать два раза <kbd>tab</kbd>, то отобразится список доступных руководств. начать лучше с:

```
$ info info
```

### info -k

с помощью опции `-k ключевые слова` можно искать документацию, содержащую любое из перечисленных ключевых слов. а если заключить строку в кавычки, будет производиться поиск именно этой строки:

```
$ info -k "regular expressions"
...
"(sed)Invoking sed" -- Extended regular expressions, choosing
...
```

затем можно просмотреть найденный документ:

```
$ info "(sed)Invoking sed"
```

---

## опция -h

многие программы имеют «встроенную» справку, выдаваемую при вызове этой программы с опцией `-h` (`--help`):

```
$ firefox -h
```