# Как найти справку к команде в bash если команда (файл) с одним названием мб в разных директориях

Tags: linux, bash, debian, man

(у меня Дебиан, но не важно)
Проблема: оказывается, что команда с одним и тем же названием может лежать (если она файл) в разных местах (+быть встроенной в оболочку), т.е. фактически это разные команды с одним названием. У них может отличаться как минимум набор параметров по умолчанию (это преподаватель показывал, это не выдумки), а мб и серьезнее всё. К каждой команде д.б. man. Как можно быть уверенным, что при вызове
**man <команда>** показывается man именно к тому варианту команды, который я использую?

Вот **whereis <команда>** показывает путь к файлу и путь к man-у

Но, например,
**whereis pwd**
даёт только:
**pwd:     /usr/bin/pwd       /usr/share/man/man1/pwd.1.gz**

а если посмотреть так:
**type -a pwd** ,
то видим:
**pwd is a shell builtin**       - как узнать, где man для этого pwd?
**pwd is /usr/bin/pwd**          - ок, для этого whereis знает, где man
**pwd is /bin/pwd**              - и как узнать, где man для этого pwd?

Comment: [доп. чтение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490703/178576)

Comment: `man $SHELL` попробуйте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> pwd is a shell builtin - как узнать, где man для этого pwd?

для встроенных в программу bash команд нет отдельных man-страниц. см. доп. информацию о встроенной команде pwd в:

```
$ man bash
```

и

```
$ help pwd
```

(help — это тоже встроненная в программу bash команда)

---

> pwd is /usr/bin/pwd - ок, для этого whereis знает, где man
> pwd is /bin/pwd - и как узнать, где man для этого pwd?

а это отголоски [новомодной фишечки](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/), в результате которой, в частности, нынче `/bin` — это символическая ссылка на `/usr/bin`.

т.е. `/usr/bin/pwd` и `/bin/pwd` — это у вас в системе один и тот же исполняемый файл. ну и man-страница к этой программе, естественно, одна:

```
$ man pwd
```

Comment: Леннарт стоит за этим новомодным идиотизмом?

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё встало на свои места

Answer (score 2):

> как узнать, где man для этого pwd?

Исполняемый фай возникает на Вашем компе не сам по себе. Если Вы его установили сами - то Вы и должны знать, куда положили его man.

Но, как правило, все программы в линухе устанавливаются через **пакетный менеджер**. У Вас debian, в котором пакетным менеджером должен быть *apt*.

Сначала определяем, к какому пакету относится этот исполнимый файл. Например:

```
$ apt-file search /usr/bin/pwd
```

После этого смотрим детальную информацию о пакете:

```
$ apt-cache show <пакет>
```

К сожалению, у меня сейчас нет под рукой debian, проверить в деталях я не могу, но (думаю) основную идею вы поняли. Для любого дистрибутива эта проблема решается в два шага:

1. По полному имени файла определяем имя пакета, из которого он установлен
2. По имени пакета определяем полный список файлов, которые входят в этот пакет.

А в списке файлов уже находит файлы *man*.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, буду использовать

Answer (score 2):

`man` не дает справок по командам. `man` - это просто структурированный справочник, который выдаёт сохранённые в него страницы. Все страницы манов есть в директории `/usr/share/man`. Абсолютно не обязательно в манах должна быть информация по нужной вам команде. Помимо команд, там есть, например, описания файлов конфигурации.

Все страницы манов разделены по разделам:

```
1.  Основные команды.
2.  Системные вызовы.
3.  Библиотечные функции, включая стандартную библиотеку языка C.
4.  Специальные файлы (обычно устройства из /dev) и драйвера.
5.  Форматы файлов и соглашения.
6.  Игры и скринсейверы.
7.  Разное.
8.  Команды системного администрирования и демоны.
```

Если встречаете ссылку на страницу мана, обычно в круглых скобочках указывают раздел мана, т.к. в разных разделах может быть ман с одинаковым именем. Например, страница `man` есть в трех разделах: `man(1)` `man(5)` и `man(7)`.

`/bin` - в современных дистрибутивах, как правило, это ссылка на `/usr/bin`. Так что `/bin/pwd` и `/usr/bin/pwd` - это один и тот же файл.

Помимо `man` есть еще `tldr`, `cheat`, `apropos`, `info`, `bropages`, `kommandr`, `yelp`.